# is there a way to find who is requesting the web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, webserver, intranet

I need to find who(ip address/domain name) is requesting my web application using code.

My login page should be accessible via internet and intranet but those who having permission they can access my site via internet other can only access via intranet.

For this i need to find their ip/domain.

Can any one help me to solve this?

Thanks!!
Tamil

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming based on the "java" tag that this is a Java EE/Servlet based web-application.  If that is the case, you can retrieve the ip-address or hostname of the requester (or proxy) by calling [getRemoteAddr()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) and [getRemoteHost()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost%28%29), respectively, on the ServletRequest/HttpServletRequest object that is passed to your Servlet's methods for handling.